# JS: How can I nest for loops WITHOUT making the first loop loop the second?

Tags: javascript, loops

Issue with my `for` loop setup:

```
var gain = prompt("Please enter the GAIN value");
var rtp = prompt("Please enter the RTP value");
var equation = function (gaininput, mdecinput) {
    rs = 2.56 * mdecinput / (0.0002 * gaininput * Math.pow(2, 24));
    return rs;
};

var sum = 0;
var co = [439.932854, 472.41802, 37.684494, 7.472018, 2.920828, 0.005184, -0.963864, -0.188732, 0.191203, 0.049025];
var cohigh = [0.183324722, 0.240975303, 0.209108771, 0.190439972, 0.142648498, 0.077993465, 0.012475611, -0.032267127, -0.075291522, -0.05647067, 0.076201285, 0.123893204, -0.029201193, -0.091173542, 0.001317696, 0.026025526];

for (var i = 0; i <= 16777215; i += 5000) {
    var rsoutput = equation(gain, i);
    var w = (rsoutput / rtp);
    document.writeln((i) + '. ' + rsoutput + '<br/>');
    var blackbox = function blackbox(b) {
        var coefficient = co[b];
            if (w<1){
                coefficient = co[b];
                }
            else{
                coefficient = cohigh[b];
                }
    return (coefficient * Math.pow(((Math.pow(w, 1 / 6) - 0.65) / 0.35, b), b));
    };
    if (w<1){
        for (var j = 0; j <= 15; j++) {
            sum = sum + blackbox(j);
            sum = sum * 273.16;
            document.writeln("YOUR SUM: " + sum + '<br/>');
        }
    }   
    else {
        for (var jtwo = 0; jtwo<=15; j++) {
            sum = sum + blackbox(j);
            sum = sum * 273.16;
            document.writeln("YOUR SUM: " + sum + '<br/>');
        }
    }
}  

var temp = prompt("Enter the temperature in KELVIN");
console.log("YOUR TEMPERATURE: " + temp * 1.86455556 + '<br/>');
```

When I run this code, what happens is that the first loop loops the `if / else` statement 16 million times. I don't want this to happen, but I have to put the `if / else` statement in this loop so that I can call variable `w`. Is there a workaround to this?

Thanks!

Comment: `w` changes its value on each iteration of the loop. Which `w` do you want the `if/else` statement to look at?

Comment: It might help to give some more context about what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is a black box that I'm building for my work. Will it help if I post the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes or explain what the black box is supposed to do

Comment: I'll edit in the code, it's a basic algorithm with user inputs

Comment: Edited in. If you've got any help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry but I still have no idea what you're trying to do. Can you edit your question to explain what format output you expect to see. Do you really want to be multiplying `sum` by 273.16 each time you add something to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you dont want the the if statements to be run inside the loop then I would move them out, if the only issue is accessing the W variable from outside the loop then move the delaration of "var w;" outside (above) the loop as well. Then the if statements can access it too.

```
var w;
for (var i = 0; i <= 16777215; i += 5000)
{
    w = (rsoutput / rtp);
    **do stuff**
}
if (w<1)
{
}
else
{}
```

Comment: The problem is that the w variable requires the for loop.

Comment: You dont have to give it a value until it enters the for loop, I edited my response with a little code it should be what you need.

Comment: He can't do that. I see w change its value in every loop

Comment: That is true, maybe I am not understanding what the intended action is. Would you like the if statement to act on w every time w changes? If so you're current solution is correct.